# While loop not breaking even with the 'break' statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner at python and programming in general so I've no idea what's wrong with my code. I'm trying to break out of the while loop but it's not working. Also, the fibonacci number code is not working as well. All the numbers between 1 to 1000 are interpreted as FIB numbers.

```
import collections
import threading


def main():
    my_list = []
    i = 0
    time_second = int(input("Please input seconds\n"))

    def sample():
    threading.Timer(time_second, sample).start()
    # Counts the frequency of number in a list

    ctr = collections.Counter(my_list)
    print(ctr)

sample()

first_number = int(input("Please enter the first number\n"))
my_list.append(first_number)

while True:
    user_input = input("Enter number\n")
    

    if user_input.isnumeric():
        user_input = int(user_input)

        # check for Fibonacci number

        def fibonacci(n):
            if n == 1:
                return 1
            if n == 2:
                return 1
            elif n > 2:
                return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)

    if user_input in range(1, 1001):
        print("FIB")

    my_list.append(user_input)

   if user_input == 'q':
        print("Bye")
        break


  main()
```

Comment: I don't see the `break` statement in the provided code.

Comment: I don't see `my_list` being defined before `.append(user_input)` to it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce a while loop not breaking error. When I run your code I exit when typing "quit"

Comment: there are a few things wrong with your code, u have not defined i, my_list. I can't see where have you used break statement in this code?

Comment: you have to initialize my_list outside the function and correct your indentation

Answer (score 0):

Your function is in an odd place and I recommend you place it outside of the while loop.

There are a few ways to exit a loop. One of these ways is by satisfying a condition for the while loop to exit from.

```
import time

def in_loop(count):
    print(f"Still in loop... on the {count} cycle")

def exited_the_loop():
    print("Exited the loop")

count = 0

while count < 10:
    time.sleep(.3)
    count += 1
    in_loop(count)

exited_the_loop()
```

Another way is to use python's break when a certain condition has been met within the loop. In this case I've used an if statement to check for this condition.

```
import time

def in_loop(count):
    print(f"Still in loop... on the {count} cycle")

def exited_the_loop():
    print("Exited the loop")

count = 0

while True:
    time.sleep(.3)
    count += 1
    in_loop(count)
    if count > 10:
        break
        
exited_the_loop()
```